# Javascript - usage of this in object methods

Tags: javascript, oop

I have javascript class defined like this:

```
function C_page() {
    this.errors = [];

    function void_log_str(L_message) {
        this.errors.push(L_message);
    }

    //and more code...
}
```

Problem is that void_log_str scope is used as this. Is there any way to go to top-level this instead?

Comment: How and where are you calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use scoping
"var _this = this;" and then refer to _this in the function body.
Or you could "bind" the function to this, e.g. using Function.prototype.bind (or a polyfill if your browser doesn't have this)

Answer (score 0):

```
function C_page() {
    this.errors = [];
    var that = this;

    function void_log_str(L_message) {
        that.errors.push(L_message);
    }

    //and more code...
}
```

I would do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) each time you call your function, to choose which value you want `this` to have;

```
function C_page() {
    this.errors = [];

    function void_log_str(L_message) {
        this.errors.push(L_message);
    }

    void_log_str.call(this, "value_of_l_message");
}
```

... or you can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to force the value of this (benefits of this is that you do this in the definition, not in the invokation);

```
function C_page() {
    this.errors = [];

    var void_log_str = function(L_message) {
        this.errors.push(L_message);
    }.bind(this);


    void_log_str("value of l message");
    //and more code...
}
```

... or you can use the `var that = this` approach;

```
function C_page() {
    var that = this;
    this.errors = [];

    function void_log_str(L_message) {
        that.errors.push(L_message);
    }

    void_log_str("value of l message");
    //and more code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
function C_page() {
    var context = this;
    this.errors = [];

    function void_log_str(L_message) {
        context.errors.push(L_message);
    }

    //and more code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) which changes depending on how the function was called, but a variable in scope that directly references the array:

```
function C_page() {
    var errors = this.errors = [];

    function void_log_str(L_message) {
        errors.push(L_message);
    }

    //and more code...
}
```

You also might use `bind`:

```
function C_page() {
    this.errors = [];

    var int_log_str = Array.prototype.push.bind(this.errors);

    //and more code...
}
```

See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for more ways to handle `this`.